# Angular trying to list data but just get [Object.Object]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some data which looks like this is the `console.log`:

```
Array(10)
  0:
   $: {id: "23" name: "name 1"}
  1:
   $: {id: "45" name: "name 2"}
```

This is currently held in `this.data`.

So in my **app.component.ts** I've got this:

First:
  `{{data}} which returns [Object].[Object]` ten times.

And secondly I've added this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let dat of data">
  <li>{{dat.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

which show's 10 blank `li`'s

How can I fix this so it shows the data?

For example, the `id`?

Comment: `<li>{{dat.$.id}}</li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<li>{{dat.id}}</li>`

To:

`<li>{{dat.$.id}}</li>`

Answer (score 0):

Also try to use safe navigation operator `?` in case of async calls always while binding to view like this

```
<li>{{dat?.$?.id}}</li>
```